# How to draw resize grip around view and resize in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, core-graphics

I have a scenario in which I want to draw an outline outside a view with resize grips in the corners like any image editing tool has. And using the grips I should be able to resize the view. Though I was able to draw by setting the layer border of the view, and dynamically added arrows to resize, but both the border and the image gets resized with the view.

Any tutorial link or, idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A resizable view control can be found here:

https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView